# Find number of pairs of disjoint sets in a list of sets

Tags: algorithm, set, time-complexity, disjoint-sets

The problem statement is as follows: given a list of n sets, each containing k integers, find the number of pairs of disjoint sets. Suppose the possible elements of the sets are positive and bounded above by c > n, and suppose k << n.

I'm trying to come up with an efficient algorithm to solve this faster than O(kn^2), which is the runtime of the naive solution.

The best strategy I could come up with involves iterating through each set in the list, and hashing the elements of the set, such that each element in the set maps to a set of the indices of the sets that contain it. Then, for the current set in the iteration, use its c elements as keys, and consider the union of the c sets of indices that are given as values by the hashtable. This resulting set of indices represents the number of sets encountered thusfar that are nondisjoint with the current set, which we can use to find the number of disjoint sets. Summing this value over the entire iteration yields a correct answer. However, since the union operation is O(n), this strategy does no better than the naive solution.

What is the most efficient possible solution for this problem?

Comment: [The same instructor or contest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795721/find-number-of-non-overlaping-pairs-of-arrays)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find number of non-overlaping pairs of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795721/find-number-of-non-overlaping-pairs-of-arrays)

Answer (score -1):

As k << n, you can reduce the complexity by:

- Sorting each set, which can be in n * k * log(k)
- Then sorting all sets by first last element, n * log(n)

Now comparing needs n * (n - 1) operations, which are:

- Either comparing s1.Last to s2.First (which should be most cases, as k << n)
- Or effectively search for s1 s2 intersection which is max in k, considering s1 and s2 are sorted

Comment: Re: "comparing s1.Last to s2.First (which should be most cases, as k << n)": I don't think that's a valid assumption. I've just run some trials with sets consisting of *k* uniformly-randomly-selected elements from [1, *n*] for various values of *k* and *n*. I found that with *k* = 5, the ranges of two sets overlapped more than 99% of the time, no matter how big *n* was. The OP hasn't specified the distribution that these sets are sampled from, but I don't think you can assume it's one that will favor this optimization. (And if it isn't, then your approach is equivalent to the OP's.)

Comment: @ruakh, I agree. Won't delete this answer, but am aware there should be a better approach for this problem